# How do I turn this array into usable variables? Getting "Notice: Undefined"

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am trying to get the following array dump to work as defined variables. My terminology is probably terrible so let me know if I am not explaining this correctly.

```
array (
  '@attributes' => 
  array (
    'created' => '2018-09-26T15:56:15-05:00',
    'host' => 'www.exampledomain.com',
    'status' => 'OK',
  ),
  'items' => 
  array (
    'client' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'clientid' => '368577',
        'name' => 'Cool Company Name',
        'site' => 
        array (
          'siteid' => '567988',
          'name' => 'Cool Company Location',
          'workstations' => 
          array (
          ),
```

I am trying to do something like the following with a 'for each'

```
$array = simplexml_load_file('rmm.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($array as $data) {
    $name = $data['items']['client'][0]['name'];
    echo "$name";
}
```

Desired output: **Cool Company Name**

I am getting the following notice **Notice: Undefined index: items**

***Solved! The following code solved my issue***

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('rmm.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($xml->items->client as $data) {
    $name = (string)$data->name;
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: @MatsLindh I have updated the original question to show how the array was built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your array also has an `@attributes` element, when you iterate over the entire array and assume they all have `$data['items']['client'][0]['name']` elements, this isn't going to work.

You could instead base your start point around the `$array['items']` element so that it will have a better chance of matching the data your after...

```
foreach($array['items'] as $data) {
    $name = $data['client'][0]['name'];
    echo $name;
}
```

OR

rather than converting it to an array, you could read the data more directly using SimpleXML.  Not entirely sure of the structure, but something like...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('rmm.xml', null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($xml->items as $data) {
    $name = (string)$data->client[0]->name;
    echo $name;
}
```

You can see how instead of using array notation, SimpleXML uses object notation to access the levels of elements in the document.  The `client[0]` bit says to use the first `<client>` element (accessing multiples elements as though they are an array).

Comment: Your solution sent me on the right track and my issue is resolved! I have updated my question with the solution that I am using. Thank you!